# the differences among "Time in a day, time of a day or part of a day"

Tags: word-choice

> 1.There is no time in a day as good as dawn.
>
> 2.There is no time of a day as good as dawn.
>
> 3.There is no part  of a day as good as dawn.

Which phrase is better to describe the period in this sentence "part of a day, time of a day, or time in a day"?

Answer (score 2):

**[Time of day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20of%20day)** is [by far the most idiomatic, common way to say it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+of+day%2Ctime+of+a+day%2Ctime+of+the+day%2Cpart+of+a+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctime%20of%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20of%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20of%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0).

We don't normally use the indefinite article (like "time of **a** day"), because it would imply we were thinking of *one* day.  "Part of" is grammatical but not what we say idiomatically.  Also common is "time of **the** day", because **the** day is a specific, known phenomenon.